# Why does svelte put curly braces on scalars?

Tags: svelte, svelte-3

E.g. this from the docs:

```svelte
<canvas
    width={32}
    height={32}
></canvas>
```

What purpose do the curly braces serve here?

Comment: What would non-curly braces look like?

Comment: Like this `width=32`

Comment: That's the absence of a brace, not the presence of a brace that is not curly.  (i.e., the term "curly brace" is redundant -- just a silly comment from me on terminology).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the example you showed, it doesn't make a difference. The following are equivalent.

```svelte
<canvas width={32} height={32}></canvas>
<canvas width="32" height="32"></canvas>
```

However, using the curly braces causes Svelte to interpret it as a JavaScript expression. This means you can do math inside the curly braces...

```svelte
<canvas width={32 + 8} height={32 - 8}></canvas>
```

...or swap it out for a variable.

```svelte
<script>
  let size = 40;
</script>

<canvas width={size} height={size}></canvas>
```

Always writing curly braces means that it saves a few keystrokes if you want to make the values dynamic later, but otherwise doesn't impact how the component is rendered.

Comment: Are you sure about that? I spoke to someone else about this and they said that what it does is cast that as a number type, whereas without the curly braces it would be cast as a string.

Comment: In this case you're setting attributes, so it doesn't matter. You're right that without the braces you're passing a string, and with the braces a number. However, under the hood this uses the browser's `setAttribute` function, which will convert the argument to a string anyway.

Comment: However, there are some cases (like custom elements) where you're actually setting the element's property. In this case, it does matter whether you use curly braces or not, since the type does matter. For example, if you have a `<custom-button>` element with a `required` property, `required={true}` and `required="true"` are distinct.

With regular DOM elements, you're usually setting attributes, so including the braces or not doesn't have an effect.